# How can I auto update a widget using AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

I am not hoping for fully working examples, I am just in need for a direction to start.

So to explain what I am trying to do, I have an app where users log in, log out, add content, do actions in the site etc. I want to know if it is possible using PHP and AJAX to make a widget that auto updates like this:

- Someone logged in...
- Someone added photo...
- etc..

I just want a guideline or direction to follow, how would I make real-time widget that auto updates and pull data/actions/etc.. would it be time interval update?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to store a list of actions that you want displayed in the widget, for example you can create a database table with (id, created_at, action_description) and whenever a user performs an action that should be displayed in the widget (e.g uploaded a photo, etc), insert a record in that table (note this is not very efficient and does not scale well if you have many users)
Second, on the browser side, you periodically call a function (with setInterval for example) to query the server for updates and update the widget

The above solution is very simplistic and wont scale.
Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setTimeout()` javascript method to trigger a reload of your widget every X milliseconds.

```
var delay = 5000; // 5 seconds
setTimeout('refresh();', delay );
function refresh(){
   doAjaxCall(); // ajax call to get new data and update the widget
   setTimeout('refresh();', delay ); // schedule next refresh
}
```

It might be better to put the reschedule (the last line) inside the ajax callback to start the timer only when the current refresh is finished.

Comment: dont use string literals for `setTimeout` and `setInterval` because browser invokes `eval` function in this case. Write just `setTimeout(refresh)`. Functions in JS are objects